# Remove Single Quote from the column value in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Guys i want the following oracle sql query to print the following value. I want to remove single quote from the column value. Let me know how to do that

```
select MSGID from schemaname_interface_daily_20110427 ;
```

**Input:**

```
X'414d51204545415837313150202020204d54a9e423d31a16'
```

**Output:**

```
X414d51204545415837313150202020204d54a9e423d31a16
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
select replace (MSGID, '''', '') from schemaname_interface_daily_20110427;
```

[Complete `REPLACE` function's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions134.htm).